# Js executes code that is after a for loop before the loop finish

Tags: javascript, for-loop, synchronous

I know that JavaScript executes loops synchronously. So I don't understand why in the code below alert runs before the end of the for loop. I expected js to first complete the loop and then to execute the alert function. Instead, the for loop starts calling the console.log("loop"), and after a couple of seconds the alert gets executed while at the same time the console.log continuous to print the text "loop".

```js
for(let i=0; i<100000; i++){
  console.log("loop");
}

alert("hello world");
```

Comment: The developer console in browsers is free to buffer messages (and indeed, many consoles would just group that to a `x100000 loop`). If you consider `console.log` to be a "fire-and-forget" function that just enqueues a message to get logged, it makes sense.

Comment: The code works.

Comment: It *seems* like the alert comes before the logs in this snippet, though I'd wager that's because of how stacksnippets is built

Comment: AKX is right. This is just a side effect of how developer tools' console view works. You can just add `i` to the alert text and see that loops finish before alert :) no magic 

Comment: if insted of alert i had: document.addEventListener('keydown', someFunction); then the event listener will start listening for keydown after the loop is complete? I'm asking this question because I'm thinking that if we have a js file with a really big loop that will take 10secs to complete and we also declare the above event listener after the for loop then if a user presses a keyboard key when the loop is still running the browser will not fire the handler because the execution hasn't arrive at the line of the listener declaration? My assumption is true?  @AKX

Comment: @user17884136 Any keypresses that occur after the handler is registered and before the big loop finishes _could_ be intercepted (but might not be), but `someFunction` will only be called after the loop finishes, since JavaScript in browsers is single-threaded.

Comment: @user17884136 To add to the last comment, due to a single-thread JS is unable to process events that the browser intercepts when JS is busy. A long running loop would make the page unresponsive. And even if the event listener is added at the end of the loop that would still happen during the time that JS is busy. And only then all queued events would be processed. So in browsers that queue events during unresponsive page time `someFunction` would be called even for 'keydown' events that happened during the loop execution before the listener was added. You can try it in a few browsers.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is how the browser can add the callback of the keydown event to a queue before the execution arrives at the line of the listener declaration. In that line, we say to the browser to listen for this event and so before the completion of the big loop browser shouldn't know that he must add a callback in a queue that will be executed when the stack is empty. How browser listens for keydown event before we tell him to with document.addEventListener. Thanks for your time! @AKX